# Offline bots (alone against bots)

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I don't know how to change the number of bots in play. I'd like to know how to change team settings to adjust a one versus three or one versus five. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8):

You can disable the teambalance using these commands in the console(after creating the game):

```
mp_limitteams 0
mp_autoteambalance 0
```

Then you can use `bot_add_ct` or `bot_add_t` to add bot to the according teams.

To remove bot,use `bot_kick name`

Comment: This does not work, or no more. "Team is full"

Comment: There is a limit of 10 on each side so the maximum will be a 1 v 10

Comment: @Alphex the current limit for me is 8. How do we get more than 8 per side?

Answer (score 1):

To get these work, I made two config files myself, 'bott' and 'botct'.

They go like this:

`mp_limitteams 0`

`mp_autoteambalance 0`

`bot_kick`

`bot_join_team t`

`bot_quota 5`

`mp_restartgame 1`

*bot_join_team*: `t` for terrorists, and `ct` for counter-terrorists.

*bot_quota* tells how many bots to join.

*mp_restartgame 1* is needed to get those settings work.